# how to set pagingtoolbar input item value

Tags: extjs

I have a problem here.
I bind a store on the pagingtoolbar which has more than one page. For example I change current page to the page 2, then I change the store content which has only one page by a search form  . The grid loads the collect data, but the input item still shows that it's in page 2, where I want it to show 1 after I call the search event.
I don't want to use store.loadPage(1) because this will cause one more exchange between the server, can anyone helps me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
grid.store.currentPage = 1;
grid.down('pagingtoolbar').onLoad();
```

Comment: Works! I am using store.loadRawData(response) and its not updating the page and "Displaying x of n". When I called the pagingtoolbar.onLoad() it was able to work. I will using this, however, just a question, I looked at 4.2.1 documentation and found that this is a private method of pagingtoolbar, hopefully this should be ok to call?